# how to display only a field of a relationship using API Resources in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

I am using Laravel Orion and would like to display the environment relationship , I have this controller:

PostsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\V1;

use App\Models\User;
use Orion\Http\Controllers\RelationController;

class PostsController extends RelationController
{
    protected $model = User::class;

    protected $relation = 'posts';

    public function filterableBy(): array
    {
        return ['environment.type'];
    }

    public function includes(): array
    {
        return ['user', 'environment'];
    }
}
```

PostResource

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class PostResource extends JsonResource
{ 
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request) + [
            'environment' => new EnvironmentResource($this->whenLoaded('environment'))
        ];
    }
}
```

App/Models/Post

```
<?php 
class Post extends Model
{   
    public function environment(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Environment::class);
    }
}
```

this the response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "..",
            "title": "..",
            "body": "...",
            ....        
        }
]
}
```

I want to load the environment information but is not displaying the **environment** key. What can I do?

Comment: Set `Post::$appends` as needed. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: Add protected $with = ['environment']; to your model. Which will automatically load the environment relationship whenever a Post is retrieved.

Comment: Your methods are not working, but I did this:  $this->environment->type , and it its working, but I am not quite sure to use it, because it may be causing the n+1 issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using php 8 or above then you can use it's null safety feature like below and it is also n+1 safe.

```
'environment' => $this->whenLoaded('environment')?->type
```

And if you are below then it would be like

```
'environment' => $this->whenLoaded('environment') ? $this->environment->type : '';
```

Comment: I am using php 8, so I used the first approach and got this error: Undefined property: Illuminate\\Http\\Resources\\MissingValue::$type , but, using the second approach is working fine, thanks